# Check if <li> is last in ul that has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list like

```
<ul>
  <li class="tool"></li>
  <li class="tool"></li>
  <li class="tool"></li>
  <li class="tool"></li>
  <li class="example"></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to check for something like `$('li').is('.tool:last')` to see if certain list is last in list, where I need to ignore `.example` one, hence can't really use `:last-child` here, but for some reason I am not getting a desired result. How can I check if list is last in the list that has class `.tool`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the last tool element and then check whether it is last-child or not:

```
var istoollastchild = $('li.tool:last').is(':last-child');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u1entnde/)**

Comment: But wouldn't .example still be seen as list child? I need to find out if it is last list item inside ul that has class of .tool

Comment: @Ilja This doesn't answer the question as you formulated it: `How can I check if list is last in the list that has class .tool?`. Otherwise, this would be more relevant: `$('#ul1 li:last-child').is('.tool')`

Comment: @A.Wolff I can now figure out if last .tool list element is last child, if not I know that there is .example one at the end.

Comment: @Ilja It seems i didn't understand the question because i was guessing you want to ignore other class element. But ya, makes sense

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry for confusion, well I just needed to know if particular .tool is last .tool in the list, now by knowing if it very last .tool is last-child or not I can make assumption if there is .example after it, hence do further stuff

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li.tool').is(':last-child');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter it, e.g:

```
var $lastLIsTool = $('ul li.tool').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).nextAll('li.tool').length
});
```

### -DEMO-

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 if (selected_object.is(current_object)) {
   ...    
}
```

Use this code It will help you

```
<ul>
  <li class="tool">Not Last</li>
  <li class="tool">Not Last</li>
  <li class="tool"> Not Last</li>
  <li class="tool">Last</li>
  <li class="example">Not Last</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var lastLiWithTool = $('li.tool:last');
    $('li').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(lastLiWithTool)) {
          alert("last li with tool");   
        }else{
        alert("not last li with tool"); 
        }
    })
</script>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8v10rx9u/

Comment: `:last` pseudo selector works in document context, this won't hanlde multiple UL elements. Now it depends OP expected behaviour

Comment: Alternative:  `var lastLiWithTool = $('li.tool').last();`